# Opening jsTree links in iframe

Tags: javascript, jstree

Pardon my lack of js skills...

I'm using jsTree to create a navigation tree for a project and I'm having issues getting the selected item's link to open up in my 'content' iframe. I've searched high and low but nothing seems to work. Below is the js code I have now, it opens the link in the 'nav' frame instead of the 'content' one.

```
$(function () {
$("#navigation").jstree({
 "themes" : {
  "theme" : "default"
 },
 "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "ui", "hotkeys" ]
});
$("#navigation").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var href = data.rslt.obj.children("a").attr("href");
    // this will load content into a div:
    $("#link").load(href);
    // this will follow the link:
    document.location.href=href;
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
window.parent.frames['content']
```

May be this will help a bit. 
Or that one:

```
window.top.frames['content']
```

depending on the parent of your 'content' frame

Comment: Tried out those by replacing the `document.location.href` in my original code but no dice, I'm I implementing it correctly?

Comment: Use firefox (FireBug addon should be present). Open FireBug on your page by pressing F12 ... go to section "Script" ... find the place where the `document.location.href` is executed and put a breakpoint there ... then execute your code and when the breakpoint is reached in the right window of FireBug ("Watch") test for example the following: `window.top.frames` ... you will get an array having all top frames ... find your frame in that way or test another similar scripts

Comment: Stupid me. It was an IE issue. The `window.top.frames` works perfectly. Thanks for your help!